# Js custom video controls. mute video input range element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am really new in javascript and I am making some custom video controls with js. I have a span element with mute/unmute icon and when hovered over a child element appears with input range bar to select the wanted level of valume. The problem is that whenever I click on the child element (the input type range bar) the icon of the parent element changes and also the volume mutes and unmutes on each click. How would I fix this?

```
<html>
    <span id ="volbtn" class = "fas fa-volume-up">
        <input type ="range" value = "1" min ="0" max ="1" volume ="1"  step="0.1" id ="volbar"/>
    </span>
</html>
```

Event listener:

```
volCtrl.addEventListener("click", muteVolume);

function muteVolume () {
    if (video.muted) {
        video.muted = false;
        volCtrl.removeAttribute("fa-volume-up");
        volCtrl.setAttribute("class", "fas fa-volume-mute");
    } 
    else {
        video.muted = true;
        volCtrl.removeAttribute("fa-volume-mute");
        volCtrl.setAttribute("class", "fas fa-volume-up");
    }
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QQXW.png)

Comment: Please be consistent and stop using spaces between properties and the first `"`

Answer (score 1):

#### Your main issue:

Your `input` is wrapped inside the `span` - therefore on input click the event bubbles up to the parent SPAN triggering *mute*.

---

#### Better custom video events handling:

I'll use the *older* `fa` icons, but feel free to modify the CSS per the new `fas` specs.
The JavaScript example is pretty self-explanatory, but feel free to ask for guidance if you get stuck!

Don't miss the newly introduced `.is-muted` and `.is-paused` CSS classes!
It's what makes the *trick*, along with [the JS's `classList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Follow this rules:

- The **custom UI** elements should only manipulate the `video` Element properties.
- The **custom UI elements appearance / styles** should be handled exclusively by the [events raised by the `video` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events):

```js
const video   = document.getElementById('video');
const playBtn = document.getElementById('playBtn');
const muteBtn = document.getElementById('muteBtn');
const volBar  = document.getElementById('volBar');

// CUSTOM UI ELEMENTS EVENTS
// They should only change the `video` properties! 
// REMEMBER: we don't handle the UI appearance here
playBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  video[video.paused?'play':'pause']();  
});
muteBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (!video.volume) return;  // Do nothing if there's no volume whatsoever
  video.muted = !video.muted; // Toggle muted state
});
volBar.addEventListener('input', (evt) => {
  video.volume = evt.target.value; 
});

// VIDEO EVENTS - AND UI STYLES
// Triggered on video property value change
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events
video.addEventListener('play',  handlePlayPauseUI );
video.addEventListener('ended', handlePlayPauseUI );
video.addEventListener('pause', handlePlayPauseUI );
video.addEventListener('volumechange', handleVolumeUI );
// TODO: Handle also 'progress', 'ratechange', etc...

function handlePlayPauseUI () {
  playBtn.classList.toggle('is-playing', !video.paused);
}
function handleVolumeUI() {
  volBar.value = video.muted ? 0 : video.volume;
  muteBtn.classList.toggle('is-muted', video.muted || !video.volume);
}
```

```css
video {display: block; max-width: 500px;}

.fa {
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fa.is-muted:before{           /* I used .fa, you use .fas */
  font-family: "FontAwesome";  /* Fix also the family name if needed */
  content: "\f026";            /* HEX for the "mute" icon (find yours in the cheatsheet CSS docs)*/
}

.fa.is-playing:before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content:"\f04c";             /* set here the HEX for pause icon */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<video id="video" autobuffer controls>
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>

<span id="playBtn" class="fa fa-fw fa-play"></span>
<span id="muteBtn" class="fa fa-fw fa-volume-up"></span>
<input id="volBar" type="range" value="1" min="0" max="1" volume="1" step="0.1">
```

Thanks to the above approach, it **makes no difference** if you manipulate the `video` default UI-handlers or the handlers of your custom UI.
With that lesson learned, you're now welcome to add the missing functions for 'progress', 'ratechange', and other VideoElement Events, and finally remove the `controls` property from the HTML `video` element.